# Strange expand on tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I don't understand why the following code fails with the error

```
ERROR: File ended while scanning use of \thmt@collect@body.
```

Indeed when I define

```
before upper={\begin{thm}[my title]}
```

it works, but when I use

```
before upper={\begin{restatable}[my title]{thm}{myrestatecommand}}
```

it fails, while the code should be equivalent. Any idea why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, thm-restate}
\usepackage{thmtools} %%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\providecommand*\thmautorefname{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\providecommand*\corollaryautorefname{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\providecommand*\lemmaautorefname{Lemma}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Works:
\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{theorem}{}{ %
    blank,
    breakable,
    before upper={\begin{thm}[my title]},
      after upper={\end{thm}},
}

% Fails:
\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{theoremRestate}{}{ %
    blank,
    breakable,
    before upper={\begin{restatable}[my title]{thm}{myrestatecommand}},
      after upper={\end{restatable}},
}

\begin{document}

%% Works:
\begin{restatable}[my title]{thm}{myrestatecommanda}
  This theorem works
\end{restatable}

%% Works:
%% Does not work:
\begin{theorem}
  This theorem does not work
\end{theorem}

%% Does not work:
\begin{theoremRestate}
  This theorem does not work
\end{theoremRestate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, theorem doesn't really work for me either, at least it doesn't generate a tcolorbox.  You could just create a new environment which uses tcolorbox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well what's the fundamental difference between restatable and thm? And I really want to be able to restate theorems, so I don't see how tcolorbox can do that for me.

Comment: It appears that restateable is based on \NewEnviron while thm is based on \newenvironment.  IIRC, you cannot nest Environs.  You might be able to get it to work using a savebox.